# EJB Interceptors in Weblogic

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic, aop

I have an EJB in Weblogic 10.3 that has en EJB interceptor defined for it like such:

```
@Stateless(name="MyEJB")
@Interceptors ({AuditInterceptor.class})
public class MyEJBImpl extends BaseEJB implements MyEJB
```

It appears as if the interceptor advice is only being applied to certain methods in the EJB.  I am using the @AroundInvoke annotation in the interceptor.  Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: Can you give a little more information about which methods aren't being intercepted?  Methods called from other methods, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually seems to be a bug in Weblogic 10.3.  What is happening is the MyEJB interface had some methods in it that were being intercepted, but that interface was extending another interface and the methods that were defined in the super interface were not being intercepted.  I moved all of the method definitions to the MyEJB interface and removed the interface inheritance and now all methods are being intercepted as expected.